# Failure to connect to derby database using ij from .bat file

Tags: sql, jdbc, derby

I have a java application from which I need to delete and insert data into a local JDBC derby database. I'm trying to execute a SQL script that does this using the ij utility. I've written a batch file to handle this.

```
C:
C:\Progra~1\Sun\JavaDB\bin\ij.bat
connect 'jdbc:derby:D:\Documents and Settings\user\My Documents\mydatabase';
run "D:\Documents and Settings\user\sqlscript.sql";
disconnect;
exit;
```

When I run the batch file, the command prompt will execute up to line 2. The ij utility will load in the command prompt, but then the rest of the commands won't be run. I've tested each line by hand and it works fine (as does the SQL script). Is there anything I need to add to the batch file to make the last 4 lines execute? Thanks.

Comment: you need to check if the spaces in Documents and Settings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put these commands in a file called 'commands.txt'

```
connect 'jdbc:derby:D:\Documents and Settings\user\My Documents\mydatabase'; 
run "D:\Documents and Settings\user\sqlscript.sql"; 
disconnect; 
exit;
```

then run ij as follows from your batch file:

```
C:\Progra~1\Sun\JavaDB\bin\ij.bat commands.txt
```

You might have the add the exact path to to commands.txt if it is not in your current folder.

Comment: That seems to be getting me a bit farther. It looks as through the commands run, but I'm getting an error: "ERROR 42X01: Syntax error: Encountered "run" at line 1, column 1. Any unrecognized commands are treated as potential SQL commands and executed directly." Is it trying to execute the run command as a SQL command instead of opening the SQL script?

Comment: I should add also that the database does not get updated either.

Comment: did you create the ij.bat file yourself?

Comment: according to the doc:http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.9/tools/ttoolsij11815.html you can provide ij with an input file where it will read the commamnds from. I updatdd my answer to reflect this point